# C library strip symbols increases code size

Tags: c, strip

I merge some object code (*.o) to a library (*.a) in C. I wanted to reduce the visible external symbols to the ones that will be used in the binary (symbols which are not used, shall not be visible).

I used the following for the strip approach:

```
objcopy --strip-all\
--keep-symbol visible_Function1\
--keep-symbol visible_Function2\
objectCode.o libraryCode.a
```

The map file looks as expected (seeing only symbols which are specified). But compared to the non-strip approach, I get an increased code size (*TEXT*) for the *.a file, building the same binary.

Any idea why the code size is increase when strip is used?

Comment: Stripping a symbol doesn't imply the code won't be in the text section. It just means it won't export the symbol name.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: The fact that stripping does not remove code would explain a lack of a decrease in code size. It does not explain an increase.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, I think we need to know how much increase are we talking about. I wouldn't reason about small increases. Could be from multiple factors.

Comment: What system? What tools versions? Can you reduce the code and produce a [minimal completenverifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya: State the factors. Why not reason about small increases? A question has been asked. The goal is to answer it.

Comment: One hypothesis is the linker uses symbol names to know where functions begin and end. When the linker knows which sequences of code belong to which functions, it may be able to remove code for unused functions. When symbols are stripped, it cannot do this.

Comment: The code increase is roughly 700 bytes (~16k total code size).

Answer (score -1):

you need to enable optimization likw -O1 or -O2 while creating libraty.

**note** : this should be used while compiling your application in which you are including this library, optimization will not remove function if you are using it somewhere in your code where you are including your library.if you doesn't want anybody else to use those functions then keep in local.